# Confluent Schema Registry timed out error

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I'm using Avro schema to write data to Kafka topic. Initially, everything worked fine. After adding one more new field(scan_app_id) in avro file. I'm facing this error.

> Avro file:
>   {
>
> "type": "record",   "name": "Initiate_Scan",   "namespace": "avro", 
>   "doc": "Avro schema registry for Initiate_Scan",   "fields": [
>       {
>         "name": "app_id",
>         "type": "string",
>         "doc": "3 digit application id"
>       },
>
> ```
> {
>   "name": "app_name",
>   "type": "string",
>   "doc": "application name"
> },
> {
>   "name": "dev_stage",
>   "type": "string",
>   "doc": "development stage"
> },
> {
>   "name": "scan_app_id",
>   "type": "string",
>   "doc": "unique scan id for an app in Veracode"
>  },
> {
>   "name": "scan_name",
>   "type": "string",
>   "doc": "scan details"
> },
> {
>   "name": "seq_num",
>   "type": "int",
>   "doc": "unique number"
> },
> {
>   "name": "result_flg",
>   "type": "string",
>   "doc": "Y indicates results of scan available",
>   "default": "Y"
> },
>  {
>    "name": "request_id",
>    "type": "int",
>    "doc": "unique id"
>  },
>   {
>     "name": "scan_number",
>     "type": "int",
>     "doc": "number of scans"
>   }   ] }
> ```
>
> Error:
>    Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException:
>   Error registering Avro schema:
>   {"type":"record","name":"Initiate_Scan","namespace":"avro","doc":"Avro
>   schema registry for 
>   Initiate_Scan","fields":[{"name":"app_id","type":{"type":"string","avro.java.string":"String"},"doc":"3
>   digit application
>   id"},{"name":"app_name","type":{"type":"string","avro.java.string":"String"},"doc":"application
>   name"},{"name":"dev_stage","type":{"type":"string","avro.java.string":"String"},"doc":"development
>   stage"},**{"name":"scan_app_id","type":{"type":"string","avro.java.string":"String"},"doc":"unique
>   scan id for an
>   App"},**{"name":"scan_name","type":{"type":"string","avro.java.string":"String"},"doc":"scan
>   details"},{"name":"seq_num","type":"int","doc":"unique
>   number"},{"name":"result_flg","type":{"type":"string","avro.java.string":"String"},"doc":"Y
>   indicates results of scan
>   available","default":"Y"},{"name":"request_id","type":"int","doc":"unique
>   id"},{"name":"scan_number","type":"int","doc":"number of scans"}]}

INFO Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer:1017) 
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Register operation timed out; error code: 50002
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:182)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:203)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:292)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:284)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:279)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerAndGetId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:61)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:93)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:72)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:54)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedSerializer$Wrapper.serialize(ExtendedSerializer.java:65)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedSerializer$Wrapper.serialize(ExtendedSerializer.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:768)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:745)
    at com.ssc.svc.svds.initiate.InitiateProducer.initiateScanData(InitiateProducer.java:146)
    at com.ssc.svc.svds.initiate.InitiateProducer.topicsData(InitiateProducer.java:41)
    at com.ssc.svc.svds.initiate.InputData.main(InputData.java:31)

I went through [Confluent documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html) about 50002 error, which says

> A schema should be compatible with the previously registered schema.

Does this mean I cannot make changes/update existing schema ?

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you share the configuration properties of schema registry along with the Avro schemas?

Comment: updated with avro schema details and complete error

Comment: In our case, when we run the app the first time with a new app ID, this error is thrown. But when we run the second time with the same app ID, it runs. How to debug that?

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the link says `50002 -- Operation timed out`. If it was indeed incompatible, the response would actually say so.

In any case, if you add a new field, you are required to define a `default` value.

This way, any consumers defined with a newer schema that are reading older messages know what value to set to that field.

[A straight-forward list of allowed Avro changes I found is by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/database/nosql-12.2.4.4/GettingStartedGuide/provideschema.html#change-schema-in-store)

> Possible errors are:
>
> - A field is added **without a default value**

Comment: {
       "name": "scan_app_id",
       "type": "string",
       "doc": "unique scan id for an app in veracode",
       "default": "9999"
       }

same errors even after adding default value.

Comment: I would start with general network debugging. Can you `curl` that URL outside of your Java app? Is the server accepting connections from your application? Firewall rules, etc?

Comment: yes if i remove that new field. even now, it's all working fine. So, I don't think there's any issue with network connections.

Comment: This is unfortunately not the case. We're upgrading an app with a newer schema that should still be compatible, but for some reason we're getting the same timeout exception. The application starts fine with the older schema. It doesn't seem to be an actual timeout, just a bug in the schema registry causing a timeout internally perhaps

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek You'd need to get the logs from the Registry, not your client to debug the problem

Comment: @OneCricketeer the logs showed nothing. Unfortunately in the end it seemed to actually have been a timeout, because our Kafka cluster was extremely overloaded and apparently just consistently didn’t have time to validate these schema changes.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek The broker itself doesn't validate the message. Perhaps the registry consumer did not consume the schemas topic?